# How to show that $\{(x,y):y \in [x, \infty), x \in \mathbb{R}\} $ is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to show that
$$E=\{(x,y):y \in [x, \infty), x \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
is a measurable set in the Borel $\sigma-$algebra in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

My attempt was define a measurable set
$$E_n=\bigcup_{k=-n2^n}^{n2^n}\left\{\left[\frac k{2^n},\frac{k+1}{2^n}\right)\times\left[\frac{k}{2^n},\infty\right)\right\}$$
Then my hypothesis is that
$$E=\limsup_n (E_n)$$
But I don't know if the above equality hold. Even if it's true, I don't know how to show that this is the case. 
It would be awesome if someone can tell me how to prove it.

Comment: You may also see it as the area above the graph of $y=f(x)=x$, which is a continuous function.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I understand that $f(x)=x$ is continuous function, but how can I use this to show that the area above (set of points) is a Borel set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $E$ (please, re-edit the question by putting the braces in the definition of $E$) is a closed set of $\mathbb R^2$. The Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the small $\sigma$-algebra containing all the open sets of the topology (hence all the closed sets).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have edited the question to include {}. It makes sense that close set in the topology in $\mathbb{R}^2$ implies measurable set is a Borel set. Thank you!